# Nginx redirect not applied

Tags: nginx, server, webserver

I am configuring an nginx server at the moment and I have two domain types:

- www.example.com
- example.com

On the server I added a new server block with the following code to redirect every incoming requests to the domain without www.

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

The problem is that I only got HTTP 200 instead of 301. 
The changed file is: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

What am I missing? I did exactly how the documentation says in Digital Ocean.

Comment: Have you restarted nginx? Post the output of `curl -I http://www.example.com/`

Comment: Yes I did and also reload the configuration file too. After that I did a test with curl as you mention but only I got is HTTP 200.

Comment: Are there any other `server` blocks that you left out of the config that you gave?